# Turn a .R file into an actual Shiny application on Ubuntu Server

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

I have developed several Shiny apps in Rstudio and I'm now attempting host them through my own Shiny server on an AWS instance of Ubuntu 16.04. My issue is that I do not understand how to translate the .R file into a Shiny application that can be viewed as a webpage.

I was able to successfully install the latest versions of R, Rstudio, and Shiny on my Ubuntu instance and I am also able to successfully view my Shiny server as a web page via port `3838`.

I then copied (via `scp`) a file from my local machine into my Ubuntu instance and placed it in the same directory that feeds my Shiny server webpage, which happens to be: `/opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps`. The obvious problem is that the two existing applications in this folder (`hello` and `rmd`) look like programs in my terminal because they are colored blue and do not contain an extension. The file that I have placed there with them is `test_shiny.R`.

How or where do I place the `test_shiny.R` file so that it is able to be viewed through my webpage?

I am brand new to Linux/Ubuntu.

Below is the contents of `test_shiny.R`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("text", label = "Text", value = "test"),
  textOutput("textout"))


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$textout <- renderText({
    paste("Input text is:", input$text)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You should create folder and inside it put ui.R and server.R files. Have a look here http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/

Comment: @KiprasKančys thanks. you are correct. I did that and it worked. I mistook `hello` and `rmd` as programs, but they were in fact folders with the ui.R and server.R files inside of them, as you mentioned. My app now works!

Comment: 'As of version 0.10.2, Shiny supports single-file applications. You no longer need to build separate server.R and ui.R files for your app; you can just create a file called app.R that contains both the server and UI components.' See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html

Answer (score 0):

You should create folder and inside it put ui.R and server.R files. Have a look here [shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/)
                    – Kipras Kančys

you are correct. I did that and it worked. I mistook `hello` and `rmd` as programs, but they were in fact folders with the ui.R and server.R files inside of them, as you mentioned. My app now works!
                    – bshelt141